# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, odbc, ola-hallengren

I recently upgraded from SQL Server 2017 Express to SQL Server 2019 Express and installed Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 18. However, a sqlcmd script to back up all databases, using Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution, still wants to use Microsoft ODBC Driver 17. I uninstalled Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. Now I am getting the below error when I run the script in a .cmd file via the Windows Task Manager.

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :  Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

How can I get sqlcmd to use the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 18?

Comment: Did you install the 64 bit version, 32 bit version, or both? Looks like one is missing.

Comment: I installed the 64-bit version of Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.

Comment: If you opens a cmd with administrator rights, th sqlcmd runs?

Comment: Yes, but it throws the error listed above if Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is not installed. I want it to run with Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.

Comment: SQLCMD requires the driver version mentioned in the error message (Microsoft ODBC Driver 17). As @SeanGallardy mentioned, make sure 32 and 64 bit versions are installed.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlcmd script absolutely will not run Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server. So I am sticking with Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. So be it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation that specifies the sqlcmd requirements:

[sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16)

> This component requires both the built-in Windows Installer 5 and the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/197080)