# What is the relationship between sqlcmd and ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, sqlcmd, sql-server-2022

I'm trying to install sql server 2022 on a build machine, and then test that I can connect to that server with sqlcmd. I previously had ODBC driver 17 and was getting errors from that command, so I uninstalled that driver and installed ODBC driver 18 instead but I'm still receiving a `Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :  Data source name not found and no default driver specified.` error from that command.
How can I be getting an ODBC driver 17 error when that driver is not installed on the machine?

This seems quite related to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314745/sqlcmd-error-microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server-data-source-name-not-fo) which remains unanswered.